# How can I determine image size and dimension before downloading the image

Tags: java, android, image, url, bitmap

I have image URLs for JPEG, GIF and PNG files. I want to check whether the images in those URLs are smaller than a specific size or not.

On the basis of that I want to download the image.

There ImageIO library in java for that but that's in the AWT library, I need something for Android.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can get image size easily using URLConnection method getContentLength()

```
 URL url = new URL("https://www.google.com.pk/images/srpr/logo4w.png");
 URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();

  // now you get the content length
 int contentLength = conn.getContentLength();
 // you can check size here using contentLength

 InputStream in = conn.getInputStream();
 BufferedImage    image = ImageIO.read(in);
  // you can get size  dimesion      
  int width          = image.getWidth();
  int height         = image.getHeight();
```

Comment: I need height and width of the image.

Comment: Then unless the server has some way of telling you what the size is, you won't find out until you can inspect the image yourself.

Answer (score 4):

Whatever **Chrylis** says is right. You can do it only after downloading . First download your image file and save it to a specific path say it **folder**.

And from there, read it and get its height and width using below code:

```
BufferedImage readImage = null;

try {
    readImage = ImageIO.read(new File(folder);
    int h = readImage.getHeight();
    int w = readImage.getWidth();
} catch (Exception e) {
    readImage = null;
}
```

**EDIT:**
To get ImageIO class in your android try the following:

go to **project properties** **java build pata->Add library**

and add **JRE System Library** and click **finish**. Now you can use **java.awt package** :)